# Comparing dates from DB

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare dates in php to decide then a function should run.
The first date is the current one and the second I get from the database, both in the yyyy-mm-dd format.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$date = new DateTime($hugRec['toDate']);
if($date < $now){echo 'inside if'}
```

The value of $date is 2019-01-02 15:22:35.000000 (when I use print_r)

The dates get type casted to string and I'm not sure how to compare them. I've Tried strtotime but with no success either.

would love to get help with that.

EDIT:
tried all your answers and stiil couldn't get inside my if statment:

```
$hug = $mysqli->query($queryHug);
$hugRec = mysqli_fetch_array($hug);
$now = new DateTime();
$date = new DateTime($hugRec['DBDate']); //obviously I changed key's name
echo '<br><br><br>DBDATE"<br>'; //obviously I changed key's name
print_r($hugRec['DBDate']); //obviously I changed key's name
echo '<br><br><br>DATE"<br>';
print_r($date);
echo '<br><br><br>NOW"<br>';
print_r($now);

 if($date < $now){
    echo '<script>alert("here")</script>';
}
```

DBDATE"
2019-01-08

DATE"
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2019-01-08 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Jerusalem )

NOW"
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2019-01-03 13:05:58.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Jerusalem )

I understand It's seems like a duplicate of other posts but apparently I'm missing something...

Comment: Just do `$date = strtotime($hugRec['toDate']);`

Comment: tried that. I get false instead of a date

Comment: Can you print the content of `$hugRec['toDate']`, showing the type of the variable

Comment: It is NOT a string, it will be a DateTime object and you can compare them as-is.

Comment: Comparing means, do you want to subtract a date from database to the current date.

Comment: Made an update. something is stiil wrong here

Comment: "2019-01-08" is not less than (that is, before)  "2019-01-03"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) will work just fine for creating datetime objects from date strings. You can then just use `<` `>` `===` operators on them for comparison.

https://3v4l.org/frgJr

```
<?php

$now = new DateTime();
$date = '1996-12-08';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);

if($date < $now) {
    echo 'HIT';
}

$date->modify("+30 year");

if($date < $now) {
    echo 'HIT';
}
```

**Output**

```
HIT
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. unfortunetley my code still doesn't get inside the if statement

Comment: @atarixdev Well the code you edited into your question has nothing to do with the code in my answer for some reason. You still do the old approach. Aswell the code you posted **can in no way** produce the output you posted :/. (E.g. your code outputs `DBDATE` but in the output it is `TODATE`). Consider using `var_dump` instead of `print_r` maybe there are hidden spaces or anything.

Comment: I did tried your answer, same result. 
using var_dump revealed nothing, both of this object contians the same type of variables.

The reason the outpit didn't excetly match the code (in the case of DBDate) is because I changed it in order to conceal my DB columns.

Comment: @atarixdev So try to create a https://3v4l.org/ that shows the problem. Should be simple to reproduce then. `var_dump()` all the input, put it into variables, copy your code and it should behave as in your local env. Then link it. You can possibly use the 3v4l I linked in my answer as a base.